# Making a pipe from `ls` to `mv`

Tags: bash, pipe, ls, rename, xargs

I am  trying to make a small utility for myself on the command line - for a given current work directory I would like to find the most recently added file and `mv` it to a name given by argument

I have been trying to achieve this via:
`ls -tr | tail -n 1 | xargs -0 -J % mv % SQL_warning_2.png`

...however bash reports:

```
mv: rename Screenshot 2020-06-22 at 17.53.23.png
 to SQL_warning_2.png: No such file or directory
```

I would guess that this means that xargs is making separate arguments via spaces in the filename: `Screenshot 2020-06-22 at 17.53.23.png`, but there is no `-print0` flag for `ls` that I am aware of.

If some of my assumptions are incorrect please excuse me - I am very unfamiliar with xargs

Comment: This is another good example why [parsing the output of `ls` is discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: is `find` a better bet?

Comment: You may be able to adapt [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389285/377345) to a question involving a similar problem.

Comment: You have spaces in the file names.  Those need special treatment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify and assign most recent file to shell variable](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/106183)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know, I am asking how I should do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to assume that your filenames don't contain newlines (you pick one out using `tail`), you could use just

```
ls -tr | tail -n 1 | xargs -I % mv -- % SQL_warning_2.png
```

The `-I %` will cause `xargs` to call the utility once *per line* read, with `%` replaced by the text of the line.  In contrast, `-J %` splits the line on spaces:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | xargs -J {} printf '"%s"\n' {}
"1"
"2"
"3"
$ echo 1 2 3 | xargs -I {} printf '"%s"\n' {}
"1 2 3"
```

You seem to want to rename the most recently modified file in the current directory.  This could be done using with the `zsh` shell as follows:

```
mv -- *(.om[1]) SQL_warning_2.png
```

This would call `mv` with the most recently modified regular file's name as the first argument. It is the `om[1]` in the glob qualifier that sorts the list of names by the mtime timestamp (newest to oldest) and picks out the first one. The preceding dot selects only regular files (not directories etc.)

From `bash`:

```
zsh -c 'mv -- *(.om[1]) SQL_warning_2.png'
```

Comment: The other answers provided me a solution, but you provided me an understanding, thankyou

Comment: With `-I %`, leading blanks, `"`, `'`,  backslash and with some implementations, bytes not forming part of valid characters would still be a problem. Empty input would also be a (minor) problem. `xargs` is really unusable unless you use the `-0`, `-r`, `-d` GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
mv -- "$(ls -t|head -n1)" new_filename
```

(here assuming the name of the newest file in the current directory doesn't contain newline characters).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with `-0`, `xargs` expects a NUL-delimited list on stdin. Here, you're feeding it the part of the name of the newest file after the last newline characters in it, followed by a newline character (that newline character is added by `ls` and not part of file name).

There is no NUL in that input, so `xargs` takes the whole input as one argument to pass to `mv` which does contain that newline character, so it would only work correctly if the name of newest file did contain one and only one  newline character and it was the last character in the file name.

Here, you'd need to make sure `ls` outputs a NUL-delimited list instead of a newline-delimited one, but I'm not aware of any `ls` implementation that can.

Or you'd need to revert to the default `xargs` input format (without `-0`) where arguments are delimited by blanks (the list of which depends on the `xargs` implementation and possibly the locale) or newlines and where `"..."` and `'...'` and `\` are used for escaping those and each other (in a different way from the same shell quoting operators). As some `xargs` implementations try  to interpret their input as text but filenames can contain any byte values (other than NUL and `/`), you'll also need to do that processing in the C locale.

```
export LC_ALL=C
ls -td ./* | awk -v q="'" '
  {gsub(/"/, "\"\\\"\"")} # escape "
  NR == 1 {printf "\"%s", $0; next}
  /\// {exit} # a / means the start of the second file
  {printf "\"\\\n\"%s", $0} # escape newlines
  END {if (NR) print "\""}' |
  xargs -J % mv % newname
```

As you can see, using `xargs` reliably is a total pain. Some `xargs` implementations also have a very low limit on the size of argument or input lines. Note that `-J` is a non-portable BSD extension.

Dealing with arbitrary file names using line-based utilities like `ls` is also very hard.

Best would be to use `zsh` which can sort the list of files by modification times by itself as @Kusalananda has shown:

```
mv -- *(.om[1]) newname
```

In `bash`, you could also do:

```
IFS= read -rd / newest < <(ls -td ./*) && newest=${newest%.}
newest=${newest%?} # strip newline
[ -n "$newest" ] && mv "$newest" newname
```

(would also work in ksh93 or zsh). Like in the previous `xargs` approach, we're using `./*` to be able to  tell on which line the second file in the list starts.